# dynamic teleport using gml

Tags: move-semantics, game-development, gml

I am making a version of asteroids and I was trying to create a system where you can teleport a specific amount of pixels into whatever direction you are facing. Every time I tried, the image would teleport to the same spot in the map. I scrapped the idea and moved on, but I remembered this site and decided that if anybody would know, it would be you guys.

I started with this concept:

//maybe jump to position//

```
x = xstart;
y = ystart;
```

but because of needing the position to be dynamic, I thought to try to implement this concept:

```
laser = instance_create(x + lengthdir_x(LenXL, image_angle) - lengthdir_y(LenYL, image_angle), y + lengthdir_y(LenXL, image_angle) +lengthdir_x(LenYL, image_angle),obj_laser);  
laser.direction = image_angle;
laser.image_angle = laser.direction;
```

this one is about shooting from a specific point on your image no matter where or what direction, so I tough I could do a jump based on a specific number of pixels from the front of the ship.

```
sprite_index = spr_teleport;
teleport = instance_create(x + lengthdir_x(TeleX, image_angle) - lengthdir_y(TeleY, image_angle), y + lengthdir_y(TeleX, image_angle) +lengthdir_x(TeleY, image_angle),obj_player);  
teleport.direction = image_angle;
teleport.image_angle = teleport.direction;
```

can somebody tell me what I am doing wrong and how I can fix this?

Comment: It is hard to understand exactly what you are doing wrong only with that little information, can you explain a little bit more?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the xstart and ystart value to whatever you want, they are not constants.

Answer (score 0):

You only need

> laser = instance_create(x+lengthdir_x(LenXL, image_angle),y+lengthdir_y(LenXL, image_angle),obj_laser);

All lengthdir_x does is return cos(argument1/180*pi)*argument0 or in words, the xposition from 0 to however far you're teleporting on the x-axis and vice-versa for "y".